# Red glitch borders on linux desktop animations

Tags: debian, gnome, drivers, nvidia

[image]I am using gnome 3.14 + debian 8 jessie + nvidia optimus graphic driver. Those borders on animations are driving me insane and I would love some suggestions on how to resolve it :( ?

PS, can someone please tell me what is the name of this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use binary Nvidia driver nvidia-319 or Bumblebee?

If you're using nvidia, try removing it and install

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee primus`

If bumblebee, try proprietary driver (need to uncomment contrib and non-free in /etc/apt/sources.list)

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus`

*For x64 Debian:*

1. Remove previously installed packages

`sudo apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus`
and reboot.

2. Install all related packages:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms intel-microcode firmware-linux-nonfree bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs primus-libs:i386 linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

3. As root, open /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf, find `KernelDriver=nvidia` and change it to `KernelDriver=nvidia-current`
4. Add yourself to the bumblebee group: `addgroup <your_username_here> bumblebee`
5. As root, open `/etc/default/grub`, find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and append "rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1" to it. Regenerate the boot image: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I have them installed, that's why it makes me wonder why it is wrong. I have the nvidia proprietary driver installed and my machine is optimus system. 

Can you give me an advice on how to remove bumblebee/optirun and make it use the default nouveau driver without completely breaking x ? PS, when I do optirun docky, the glitch still appears.

Comment: If you're using proprietary driver,run `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee-nvidia` and then install `sudo apt-get install bumblebee primus`

Comment: I tried removing bumblebee-nvidia, but when trying to install bumblebee primus, it gave "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
"

Comment: Okay, it seems that you already have it installed. Run `sudo apt-get install bumblebee primus --reinstall` and reboot.

Comment: Did it, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you use x64 Debian?

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit deb :).

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to a very similar problem, in Debian Jessie, using XFCE, Docky and compton.

After reading some posts here and there it seemed to be an issue with the kernel, so I installed a later version (4.3), and it is all working fine now.

The easiest (and maybe safest) way I found was installing the linux-libre (100% free version of linux) using these instructions: https://jxself.org/linux-libre/

I hope it will be useful.